# How to validate against upload capacity using DropZone.js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, dropzone.js

I have a value stored in a database that holds the actual capacity (capacity size in Megabytes for uploaded files) for a user. I want to validate this before each file within a queue is uploaded, so the maximum capacity isn't surpassed. I'm using *Laravel* as a framework, and *DropZone.js* for the uploading and I want to validate against this maximum capacity using the Dropzone methods.

Comment: use `maxFilesize` parameter and assign that value to this parameter. :)

Comment: when a file is uploaded i add the file size to the actual capacity in my database, so i cand do that, and i have set the dropzone for add as many files as you wish, but upload one by one.

Comment: didnt get u :(, can u please describe a little bit more ?

Comment: Ok, i m developing like a dropbox, that you have a maximun space in gb to upload as many files as you wish, but the sum of all this files cant be greater than the max capacity, so every time you upload a file the software should go to the database and see if you can upload (if the actual capacity added to the file size than you are uploading is minor than the max capacity) if so, you can upload, if not the software will show you an error, you get it?

Comment: if anyone could help it will be nice